# how to get data or record from sublist in netsuite using suitlets version 1.0

Tags: suitescript

I have created one form in that am getting data only header parts but m not getting data from subsist record please help me. I have used so many APIs but trying to get stored record type.

Answer (score 0):

From testing, the sublist structure in POST data is stored in the request parameters:

```
var sublistId = 'insertsublistid';
var valuesParam = sublistId + 'data';
var fieldsParam = sublistId + 'fields';
```

The data are delimited by the following characters:

```
var SUBLIST_FIELD_DELIM = /\u0001/;
var SUBLIST_LINE_DELIM = /\u0002/;
```

Comment: I am using 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is for SS 2.0

```
    var value = context.request.getSublistValue({
        group: 'item',
        name: 'amount',
        line: '2'
    });
```

See /app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4314828231.html